# Delphi: SendMessage don't send to FMX

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey

I successfully send message cross apps. But the code doesn't work in FMX. I can find the FMX form but no message receive at dest.

Sender code:

```
  CDS.dwData:= 0;   //Identify message
  CDS.cbData:= ByteLength(Str);
  CDS.lpData:= PChar(Str);

  if DstHandle=0 then
    DstHandle := Winapi.Windows.FindWindow(nil, PChar(TargetFormCaption));

  if DstHandle<>0 then
  begin
    Res := SendMessage(DstHandle, WM_COPYDATA, Handle, NativeInt(@CDS));
    Result:= True;
  end
  else
    Result:= False;
```

Result is true but `WMGetData` is not triggered.
Receiver code:

```
procedure WMGetData(var Msg : TWMCopyData) ; message WM_COPYDATA;
...
procedure TForm3.WMGetData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
begin
  Caption:= 'Got something !';
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forms in FMX are not able to receive messages in the same way as VCL forms.  FMX does not dispatch window messages that FMX does not use itself.

The clean way to approach this is to use `AllocateHWnd` to create a window that can receive your messages. Even for VCL apps that is the right approach because such a window is not subject to re-creation.

Comment: Another option is to subclass the Form's HWND to intercept messages before FMX sees them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9186663/65863

Comment: +1, I overwrite `CreateHandle` and create a handle with `AllocateHWnd`,  with this approach the WMGetData got triggered (with messages like activate/deactivate), `FindWindow` find FMX app but seems messages goes to elsewhere(as u say). If I use the created handle in the sender SendMessage, I got the message receiver side. Seems `FindWindow` doesn't find right handle. Any idea?

Comment: Er, don't know what CreateHandle is. Stop trying to work with the visible window that hosts the form. Create a new window, say with AllocateHWnd, and use that. It's class name is well-defined and you can give the window a unique name. Then FindWindow can find it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can find the window with its predefined params (class name `TPUtilWindow` with no title) , but `SetWindowTitle` doesn't work (beside its output is true).  Any idea?

Comment: Use `SetWindowText` or send `WM_SETTEXT`. Or create your own window class.