# Cannot type TAB in edit components in C++ Builder/Delphi with Firemonkey

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I want to write script editor in my application that I write in C++Builder with Firemonkey.
< Tab > symbol is important symbol when you edit code in TMemo(or TEdit), but if I press  - application just moves focus to next component.

I have tried to hook into the onKeyDown of the form, and TMemo component, but it seems < Tab > key is handled on lower level, and I cannot catch it.
Tried to google this question, but it seems no one bother to type tab in editors in Firemonkey framework.

How can I change behavior of the focus processor, or just configure TMemo component to not move to next component on tab key, but print it?

Comment: The tab key is typically reserved for input navigation between controls. VCL's `TMemo` has a `WantTab` property to allow the user to type tab characters. FMX's `TMemo` does not appear to have a similar feature, and it can't be enabled manually the way VCL's `TMemo` does because FMX does not use standard OS controls. Like you, I can't find any mention of this issue in online searches.

Comment: On **VCL** there is `TabStop` property in focusable components. If you set it to `false` the **TAB** will not go there ... if `false` for all of the focusable components then it should not lose focus in theory but I do not think it will do what you want... I have no **FMX** experience but its possible it has similar property ... btw why not detect change of focus and add a TAB character into feed and correct the focus  instead ? I know it would flicker a bit but its a workaround ... btw TMemo should not use TAB to change focus ... you most likely just set ti to readonly

Comment: Spektre, it is not readonly, because I can type any text into it. It also has property TabStop, but regardless of it's state, focus moved to next component. Change it manually may work, but in focus change event I do not know source of  event change, that is why do not know how to determinte if I pressed tab, or clicked on some other component. I thought about put some flag "tab pressed", and then depending on it's value do something on focus change event, but KeyDown event not fires at all if I press Tab key

Comment: @Dmitry hmm the only thing that I can think of is to create a window that contains only your `TMemo` and detect/set its focus in a timer (or on leaving focus) ... If the window does not have any borders and is docked onto your main Form you should  not see any visual difference in comparison to having just placed `TMemo`... But as Remy hinted your issue might be something else masking as such behavior. Do you forcing Focus or doing something non standard with your visual components? or messing up with message handling?

Comment: In my case I have only one TMemo in TTabControl(focus  jumps from TMemo to TTabControl's tab header), and I did not do anything except standard message handlers of component, because Firemonkey is crossplatform framework, that is why it hides all message magic under the hood. I think I will try to somehow hook into the message processing pipeline like specified here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186098/firemonkey-message-handling). But also should test this behavior on Linux, did not checked how focus works there

Comment: @Dmitry hmm the problem might be the `TTabControl` itself but I might be wrong as I am using old IDE (BDS2006) in there the component is buggy even in designer ... although I am using it but sometimes its more pain than worth ...

Answer (score 0):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
//....
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: System.WideChar; Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;

//....

procedure TForm1.KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: System.WideChar;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkTab) and (Focused.GetObject = Memo1) then
  begin
    KeyChar := #9;
    Focused.KeyDown(Key, KeyChar, Shift);
    Exit;
  end;

  inherited;
end;
```

Override TForm.KeyDown procedure like these, tab key will work ok in the memo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).